# Does anyone know the meaning behind this php error message?

Tags: php, mysql

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING is the message.  It came up from this line of code:

```
$query = ("SELECT * 
             FROM users 
            WHERE user_name = $_POST['user_name'] 
                & password = $_POST['password'] 
                & user_type = $_POST['user_type']");
```

Does anyone out there know the meaning of all this?  If so, does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Since you're a new user, I'm going to point out the vulnerability of your script to SQL injection.

Comment: One more thing, since SQL injection has been covered - PLEASE tell me you're not storing passwords in plaintext.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT u.* 
                    FROM USERS u
                   WHERE u.user_name = '%s' 
                     AND u.password = '%s' 
                     AND u.user_type = '%s' ",
                   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_type']) );

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

### Reference

- [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can't interpolate a `$_POST` like that. You need to wrap them with braces (`{` and `}`). You also don't need to quote the key names when already in a string like that.

You should also quote those values, and swap `&` with `AND`.

You also need a `;` at the end.

You also don't need to wrap it in parenthesis.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
         FROM users 
        WHERE user_name = '{$_POST[user_name]}' 
          AND password = '{$_POST[password]}' 
          AND user_type = '{$_POST[user_type]}'";
```

---

## But...

...don't interpolate user input directly like that. Use a escaping mechanism.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$user_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_type']);


$query = "SELECT * 
         FROM users 
        WHERE user_name = '$username' 
          AND password = '$password' 
          AND user_type = '$user_type'";
```

I would recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and binding parameters instead of building the SQL yourself.

Also, it would appear you your passwords that are user inputted are being directly used to compare in the database. Use some form of one way message digest, such as [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Comment: Oh, cool. You mean like so?: "SELECT username FROM users WHERE email={$_POST['email']}" ?

Comment: I question why you advised at using an escaping mechanism but still provided code which throws the user input directly into the query.

Comment: Good to see - also, thank you for commenting on the password storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_password"]);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_type"]);

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username' AND user_password='$password' AND user_type='$type' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: uh... `user_password=' OR 1 = 1 --`. Careful what you're recommending here.

Comment: Good pickup on the user_password typo, not getting the OR 1 == 1 thing though?

Comment: SQL injection. If you use that for your auth, I can bypass your mechanism complete.

Comment: Still confused - could you show me what the query would look like?

Comment: lol, he's saying he could pwn your box with a simply query since you didn't account for SQL injection.

Comment: The resulting query would look like: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='' AND user_password='' OR 1=1 -- AND user_type='$type' LIMIT 1`. Since 1 does in fact equal 1, this will bypass the authentication completely on some systems since the query won't return an empty result.

Comment: Basically marty you are allowing them to type anything from that input.  Meaning they can add whatever sql code they want.

Comment: Ah, I'm aware of mysql_real_escape_string but I figured that wasn't really answering the original question :/

Comment: @Marty Wallace If someone asks you why they can't cut bread with an axe, you shouldn't sharpen the axe or tell them they're holding it backwards - you should get them a breadknife.

Comment: Touche. I'll stick with the AS3 questions ;(

Answer (score 0):

For interpolation of one-dimensional array values into strings, use this syntax:

```
"foo = $_POST[bar]"
```

Notice no quotes.

For interpolating nested arrays or generally using the normal syntax, use braces:

```
"foo = {$_POST['bar']}"
```

In no case though do any of this with SQL queries, you need to **escape values before plugging them into queries**. So, do this:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = "%s"',
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['baz']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to account for SQL injection.

Try:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_password"]);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uesr_type"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username' AND password='$password' AND 
 user_type='$type'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggesting reading the manual a bit: http://us.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing. That link will explain to you how PHP parses variables in strings.