# Can anyone find an undefined index in this line of php code?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$username = $_POST["user_name"];
$password = $_POST["user_password"];
$type = $_POST["user_type"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username' AND user_password='$password' AND 
 user_type='$type'";
```

When run, I get an error message that states that the first three lines of code have undefined indexes.  Could someone help me figure out what went wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does anyone know the meaning behind this php error message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813436/does-anyone-know-the-meaning-behind-this-php-error-message)

Comment: Nah, that question was a problem of not encapsulating his array references properly within the quotes. This question is regarding missing array elements.

Comment: Please tell me you actually read the things about MySQL injection and password hashing from the last questions you asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["user_password"]) && isset($_POST["user_type"])){
   $username = $_POST["user_name"];  
   $password = $_POST["user_password"];
   $type = $_POST["user_type"];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username' AND user_password='$password' AND 
 user_type='$type'";
}
else{
// required value is missing
}
```

When you use $_POST you must check that the required values are in $_POST in not. So you should use `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

Well we can't see the contents of your $_POST array, but likely your form is not posting correctly, or you have misnamed your input fields, because the "user_name," "user_password," and "user_type" indexes of the $_POST array do not exist, according to the error.

Could you post the form code? Or echo $_POST and tell us what the output contains?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code so it checks whether it's there or not

```
$username = iseet($_POST["user_name"]) ? $_POST["user_name"] : '';
$password = isset($_POST["user_password"]) ? $_POST["user_password"] : '';
$type = isset($_POST["user_type"]) ? $_POST["user_type"] : ;

//NOTE - You have an sql injection vulnerability in the below code
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username' AND user_password='$password' AND 
 user_type='$type'";
```

Always check whether your indices are set or not.

Also, don't insert array values directly into your SQL like that. At least use `mysql_real_escape_string` or consider using MySQL PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php